# How to solve equations containing logarithms and exponentials

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

**Equation 1:**

$x+e=e^x$

According to Wolfram alpha : Solution of x $\approx$ *-2.6 and 1.4*

[image: Graph for x+e=e^x]

**Equation 2:**

$x-e = \ln(x)$

According to wolfram alpha, Solution for x $\approx$ *0.07 and 4.1*

[image: Graph for x-e=ln(x)]

***How does one solve equations like this?*** For exact solution they use one W() Function ... What is that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That $W$ is the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  (But I thought Wolfrom didn't use that terminology, instead "product logarithm" or something?)

**added**
The Lambert W function is inverse to the function $xe^x$.  So that means: $xe^x=y$ becomes $x=W(y)$.  In some cases there may be two real solutions.  And there are infintely many complex solutions.  Represented by "branches" of the $W$ function: $\dots, W_{-1}, W_0, W_1, \dots$.

So, let's do the problem
$$
x+e = e^x .
$$
I rearrange this:
$$
(x+e)e^e = e^{x+e}
\\
-(x+e)e^{-(x+e)} = -e^{-e}
\\
x+e = W\left(-e^{-e}\right)
\\
x = e+ W\left(-e^{-e}\right)
$$

Maple shows that the two real branches of this are:
$$
e+ W_0\left(-e^{-e}\right) \approx 2.64745
\\
e+ W_{-1}\left(-e^{-e}\right) \approx -1.42037
$$

Comment: Can you please explain your last step so as to why the W become $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$ and also how to get the value of W(a)? BTW thanks!

Comment: See the link for information on the Lambert W function.